# What's the syntax of get the user's input from jenkins's pipeline step?

Tags: jenkins, user-input, jenkins-pipeline

I build my job throuth jenkins's pipeline and useing  the  Snippet Generator to create my code like this :

```
node {
    stage 'input'
       input id: 'Tt', message: 'your password:', ok: 'ok', parameters: [string(defaultValue: 'mb', description: 'vbn', name: 'PARAM'), string(defaultValue: 'hj', description: 'kkkk', name: 'PARAM2')]

    // here I need get the text user input , like `PARAM` or `PARAM2`
}
```

As described above, what's the syntax of get parameter ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm kind of limited to test the code but I think it should be like:

```
node {
    stage 'input'
    def userPasswordInput = input(
        id: 'userPasswordInput', message: 'your password', parameters: [
            [$class: 'TextParameterDefinition', defaultValue='mb', description: 'vbn', name: 'password']
        ]
    )
    echo ("Password was: " + userPasswordInput)
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer very much . As i copy your code , it will parsed with an error . But it gave me an idea, I use code below and it works.                node {
    stage 'input'
    def userPasswordInput = input(
        id: 'Password', message: 'input your password: ', ok: 'ok', parameters: [string(defaultValue: 'master', description: '.....', name: 'LIB_TEST')]
    )
    echo ("Password was: " + userPasswordInput)
}

Answer (score 1):

```
node {
    stage 'input'
    def userPasswordInput = input(
        id: 'Password', message: 'input your password: ', ok: 'ok', parameters: [string(defaultValue: 'master', description: '.....', name: 'LIB_TEST')]
    )
    echo ("Password was: " + userPasswordInput)
}
```

with the idea Joschi give , the code above works well .Thanks for Joschi again very much.

Comment: Hi @Joschi , Thanks for the code snippet, I had a similar requirement and it helped me a lot. Just wanted to check if i want to store "userPasswordInput" in a variable or if i want to write it to a file, how can it be achieved. I tried writing to a file using the "file <<" syntax but it did not work for me. Thanks in advance for your help!